# How do I create a regular expression to accept not more than 10 digits?

Tags: regex, validation

How do I create a regular expression to accept not more than 10 digits?

thanks

Comment: The title "not more than 10 digits" is different from the question "less than ten digits" - which is it? :)

Comment: Is 10 to be included or excluded?  Title indicates included, but description indicates excluded.

Comment: The title says "not more than 10", the question says "less than 10". You have gotten answers for both scenarios. Pick carefully ;o)

Comment: @Devinb - please be a bit more forgiving. OP is clearly a non-english speaker so their english isn't going to be perfect. Also if he/she has no clue how to do this, then they have no clue. Judging by his/her other question, this is unlikely to be homework so I'm deleting that tag.

Comment: If you google Regular Expressions Tutorial, you can find 100s of links.
This person farmed out their work to us instead of looking it up themselves.

Comment: @Devinb - if we all used google then there would be no need for stackoverflow. It's a good enough question to add to SO's repository of questions.

Comment: @Kev, SO was not created as a replacement for doing your own work. It was a place where developers could get together and seek help for the questions that they *could not find* the answer to. I'm not suggesting that this question is 'too simple'. I'm suggesting that this person made NO effort to solve it themselves.

Comment: @Devinb - third rule of SO - "Be Nice" :). You're making just assumptions, plenty folk felt the question was good enough to answer.

Comment: @devinb - also how do you know that OP isn't living under a repressive regime where google might not work that well (Iran, Burma, North Korea...). 'expression' may in some wacky filter may be interpreted as 'freedom of expression'.

Comment: @Kev I am being nice. I downvoted, and I explained why I downvoted. That is the purpose of the downvote. I should have tagged "Plz-Send-Teh-Codez" instead of "homework" you're right about that. And finally, I'm certain that if "Regular Expressions" were to be flagged as illegal content, then SO would be banned.

Comment: Perhaps my question is not clear. sorry for this.Any way i have tried all this. but my situation is different.I want regular expression which will allow upto 10 digits in user control which uses text box.

Answer (score 31):

Since you've asked "how", I'll try to explain step by step. Because you did not specify which regexp flavor you are using, so I'll provide examples in [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) and [two POSIX regexp variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions).

For *simple* cases like this you should think of regular expression as of automation, accepting one character at a time, and saying whenever it is valid one (accepting the character) or not. And after each character you can specify quantifiers how many times it may appear, like (in PCRE dialect) `*` (zero or more times), `+` (one or more time) or `{`*n*`,`*m*`}` (from *n* to *m* times). Then the construction process becomes simple:

```
PRCE  | B.POSIX | E.POSIX   | Comments
------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------
^     | ^       | ^         | Unless you are going to accept anything with 10
      |         |           | digits in it, you need to match start of data;
\d    | [0-9]   | [:digit:] | You need to match digits;
{1,10}| \{1,10\}| {1,10}    | You have to specify there is from 1 to 10 of them.
      |         |           | If you also wish to accept empty string — use 0;
$     | $       | $         | Then, data should end (unless see above).
```

So, the result is `^\d{1,10}$`, `^[0-9]\{1,10}\$` or `^[:digit:]{1,10}$` respectively.

Comment: +1 nice answer. I was about to comment on different regex flavours.

Answer (score 7):

```
^\d{1,9}$
```

That will match anything from 1 digit to 9.

Since you didn't specify the regex flavor you're working with, that should get you where you need to be.  If not, tell us which regex technology you're using.

Comment: technically, not more than 10 includes 10, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

`/\D\d{0,10}\D/` (assuming "less than" includes 0)

`/\D\d{1,10}\D/` (if you want from 1 to 10 digits)

Comment: That is exactly 10 digits only

Comment: \D means "not a digit", so this matches up to 9 digits surrounded by non-digits, e.g. a123b, but not 1111111111111111111.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
^\d{,9}$
```

[perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) is a nice tutorial on regular expressions in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do the trick:

> ^\d{1,10}$

Comment: He wants LESS than 10 digits.

Comment: Note that that will also match the empty string, unlike \d{0,10}.  By itself, this regex may have issues (since the empty string is located everywhere within a string).  If the digit string is optional and this is part of a larger regex, it would be what you want.

Comment: @Zanoni The title indicates that 10 is to be included, which is why I chose to include it.  There is definitely some ambiguity between the title and the description.

Comment: That would also match strings with >10 digits since there's no requirement for matching a non-digit after matching 1..10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

/\D\d{,9}\D/ in Perl

Answer (score 0):

for "less than 10" and at least 1 you'd want, assuming it's the only value...

```
^\d{1,9}$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find at least one and no more than 9 digits in a row:

`\d{1,9}`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.regexbuddy.com/

but I'd suggest to divide concerns here, just check if the length of the string is <=10 characters after the input, you don't need regex to do that.