# Regular expression to match up to 10 digits

Tags: asp.net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a regular expression to accept not more than 10 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032877/how-do-i-create-a-regular-expression-to-accept-not-more-than-10-digits)

I want a regular expression which will allow up to 10 digits in a user control having a text box. (ASP.net 3.5).

Comment: you might want to add some more tags to this ... asp.net and aspx would be ones to start with

Comment: You got plenty of answers on the Regex yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032877/how-do-i-create-a-regular-expression-to-accept-not-more-than-10-digits

Answer (score 8):

`^[0-9]{1,10}$` or `^\d{0,10}$`

Answer (score 1):

Add regular expression validator with your textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" MaxLength="10" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rvDigits" runat="server" 
   ControlToValidate="tb"  Text="*" Display="Dynamic" 
      ValidationExpression="^\d{0,10}$" />
```

A better approach will be to use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and [jquery.numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) plugin!